# HTML JSP onclick: return functionality

Tags: html, jsp

I am new to HTML and JSP.

Below is an HTML portion of code I am trying to analyze:

```
<TD>
    <FONT size="2">
        <FONT color="#ffffd2">
            <INPUT size="40" name="from" type="text">
        </FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <INPUT type="image" border="0" name="B1" value="Submit" onclick="return validate(this.form);" src="../../../theme/Images/buttons/send.gif">
    </FONT>
</TD>
```

I am failing to understand the `onclick` action of the mentioned button:

```
onclick="return validate(this.form)
```

Please help me analyze and trace the action event.

Comment: This calls a javascript method validate. if it fails, the form is not submitted

Answer (score 0):

When the image is clicked the function `validate` is called with the form as the parameter(`this` is the image button`and its`form` property is the form its inside/associated with).
If the function returns false the form will not be submitted otherwise the form is submitted, the return before the function call is necessary for the behavior.
The button type image is a type of submit button.